# Can't connect to Google Games API with 11.0.2 Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I know stackoverflow has a lot of questions regarding this issue but this one is related with recent [changes in games development](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html). First of all there is no strict guide for integrating Games API. At least I didnt find anything fresh. This one [guide is for simple sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) and [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils) is not suitable for new changes anymore. Tried it - doesn't work. Perhaps someone already faced this issue.

I was able to connect the client but `mApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API)` stull returns `false` on `onConnected` method.

I've already added [SHA-1 keys for both release and debug versions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) and in google console I see auto-generated IDs for Web and Android clients. The last one is added as string `server_client_id`. Also I've already downloaded `google-services.json` file. Yeah, and Manifest has Meta-data:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

My current code:

**onCreate()**:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            //.requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            //.requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.GAMES), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .build();

    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            //.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

**onStart()**:

```
mApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
```

**onConnected()**:

```
 if (mApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API)) { //always returns false
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                // In this case, we are sure the result is a success.
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();

            }
        });
    }
```

Also tried [this guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) but it didn't work. I simply couldn't sign in and `resolveIssue` was called all the time. Guess it's obsolete.

Could anyone suggest **fresh** solution which was already tested to be working?